# Google Map Geocode API when API key given returns REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: php, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

When i remove the API key part, it works fine

```
$details_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $string."&sensor=false";
```

When add the api key, it says REQUEST_DENIED.

```
$apiKey = 'AIzaSyCy2C82dDZlHkwGZ_fCfgh5gBdo50Q8cE0';
$string = str_replace(" ", "+", urlencode($string));
$details_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $string."&sensor=false&key=".$apiKey;
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

This is the first time i am using the geocode API and i need to work based on a API key, because once we dont find enough of the 2500 queries per day we will purchase the pay as you go plan. (google map for business)

The API key i created was a new server key at console panel.

what wrong am i doing to not accept my api key? however when i add the API key and try via browser it works fine like below and i could see the usage reports and used quota at google console.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2140+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+IN&key=AIzaSyCUDSJ2GBE1DHupbAZT4u8gZqclkIhmb0M
```

Comment: When i make the http in to https it returns empty.

Comment: i followed the steps here as well https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

Comment: It says the key has expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api request must be sent over `https` for a start and then you will find that the key has expired.

```
$string = 'Dundee, Scotland';
$apiKey = 'AIzaSyCy2C82dDZlHkwGZ_fCfgh5gBdo50Q8cE0';
$string = str_replace( " ", "+", urlencode( $string ) );
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $string."&sensor=false&key=".$apiKey;

$cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( $cacert ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,2 );

$response = json_decode( curl_exec( $ch ), true );
$info = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );


echo '<pre>', print_r($info,1), PHP_EOL, print_r( $response, 1 ), '</pre>';
```